# What syntax am I missing this CASE WHEN statement?

Tags: sql, case-when

I am joining a location table and an employee table to get employee locations and map them back to higher-level locations (i.e., 'US' derived from 'New York City').

I have completed the join successfully but I want to test my results to understand where base locations may not have mapped to higher-level locations. The dataset is too large to eyeball it.

My server tells me the error is at or near my "CASE" syntax but I cannot figure out what. Here's the code:

```
SELECT wd.name, wd.manager_name, l.territory, l.location_name, l.market
FROM dw.mv_regional_org_chart wd

CASE

    WHEN territory = 'Brussels' THEN 'Belgium'
ELSE 'Not Belgium'
END AS 'Belgium Status'
JOIN dw.mv_dim_location l
ON l.location_uuid = wd.location_uuid;
```

Comment: syntactically, it is a `case...when...end` **expression**. [that is exactly the syntax you are missing]

Answer (score 0):

All column definitions need to go before your FROM clause:

```
SELECT wd.name, wd.manager_name, l.territory, l.location_name, l.market,
    CASE
    WHEN territory = 'Brussels' THEN 'Belgium'
    ELSE 'Not Belgium'
    END AS 'Belgium Status'
FROM dw.mv_regional_org_chart wd

JOIN dw.mv_dim_location l
ON l.location_uuid = wd.location_uuid;
```